# Simple javascript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a navigation with a sliding bar/box that follows the mouse. I manage to animate the box I'm having trouble to move the box to follow the mouse. ex. if the mouse is in nav1 the box would slide to nav1 from wherever nav the box is currently place.

I made a example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Wrcr/

HTML

```
<div id="nav" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 500px; background: red;">
    <div id="nav1"></div>
    <div id="nav2"></div>
    <div id="nav3"></div>
    <div id="nav4"></div>
    <div id="movers"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav1, #nav2, #nav3, #nav4 {
    width: 98px;
    height: 48px;
    border: thin solid black;
    float: left;
}
#movers {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
#nav:hover > #movers {
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav").hover(function(){
       $('#movers').stop().animate({'margin-left': '300px'}, 500);
    });
 });
```

Comment: could you do a jsfiddle? This would greatly help people to answer.

Comment: @Salketer There is a fiddle in the description.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what animation showing that code. But if you want to use margin left animation then you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#nav').hover(function()
   {
       $('#movers').animate({
               margin-left: '300px'
       });
   });
});
```

not tested but should work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Wrcr/4/)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#nav div").hover(function(){
            var a =$(this).position();
            $('#movers').stop().animate({'margin-left': (a.left-29)+'px'},500);

    });
});
```

Comment: @user3457998 position() will give the left.I don't know my answer is perfect

Comment: yeah it's properly working. but it is sliding all the from the left side like the initial position is left: 0. tried changing positions no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#nav div").hover(function(){
  $('#movers').stop().animate({
    'left': $(this).offset().left
  }, 500);
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5Wrcr/6/)**

Comment: Code is good, `#mover` div should exclude from hover event, because animation will be stopped when navigate mouse on `#mover` div. `$("#nav > div:not(#movers)")`

Comment: Good code but it's starting all the way to the left. same with the code from rahul.